# Basic Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap following this [Orielly Bootstrap book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027867.do).

This is the simple html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
    <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded Bootstrap and I have `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` at correct places. As per the code, we should get a row with 2 columns. But I am getting output as :

[image]

Please let me know what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: class="span8"?? i think you should be using col-md-*....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> class="span8"
> ```

It looks like the book you are reading is out of date. That is the syntax used in [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) (which is no longer supported).

Presumably you have downloaded the CSS for Bootstrap 3 or 4. Consult [their documentation for the current syntax](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template), which has changed significantly since Bootstrap 2.

Answer (score 1):

Also added the viewport meta required for bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body>
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">Span 8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Span 4</div>
</div>


 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using old syntax of Bootstrap 2. Let's switch to BS3 or 4.

For a basic thing (testing, playing, whatever). I would recommend to use CDN source for Bootstrap. And get through to all [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

**Latest compiled and minified CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Latest compiled and minified JavaScript**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "**Latest** compiled and minified CSS" — That is incompatible with the markup the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a class in `div` `container/container-fluid` .

Demo HTML5 + Bootstrap + Font Awesome Template  source [LINK](https://github.com/ashikjs/HTML5)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
          <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/5hjdafgt/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
          <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```